# Added tab & field to back office product in prestahop - how to save input properly?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I followed [this tutorial on creating a custom module for a new tab and input in the back office](http://nemops.com/prestashop-products-new-tabs-fields/#.Vxfe6npRJAM)

I don't want anything to do with languages - I have a simple text input where the user will input an INT.

In the tutorial it has us update the hookActionProductUpdate method:

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
// get the lines
// store the new field

$id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
    if(!Db::getInstance()->update('number_lines', array('number_lines'=> pSQL(Tools::getValue('number_lines'))).' AND id_product = ' .$id_product ))
        $this->context->controller->_errors[] = Tools::displayError('Error: ').mysql_error();
}
```

When I click 'save & stay' nothing happens.

My .tpl is showing it like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <input type="text" name="number_lines" id="number_lines" value="{$number_lines|htmlentities}" />
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Overall purpose is just to have a text field that the user can enter a number into and it's saved into the database in the back office of a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have table called `ps_number_lines` with columns `id_product` and `number_lines`, so your update query should looks like:

```
Db::getInstance()->update('number_lines', 
    array('number_lines' => pSQL((int)Tools::getValue('number_lines'))), 
    'id_product = ' . $id_product)
```

because now you use it wrong, for better understanding check method `update` in `classes/db/Db.php`

```
/**
     * @param string $table Table name without prefix
     * @param array $data Data to insert as associative array. If $data is a list of arrays, multiple insert will be done
     * @param string $where WHERE condition
     * @param int $limit
     * @param bool $null_values If we want to use NULL values instead of empty quotes
     * @param bool $use_cache
     * @param bool $add_prefix Add or not _DB_PREFIX_ before table name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update($table, $data, $where = '', $limit = 0, $null_values = false, $use_cache = true, $add_prefix = true)
    {
        if (!$data)
            return true;

        if ($add_prefix)
            $table = _DB_PREFIX_.$table;

        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.bqSQL($table).'` SET ';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!is_array($value))
                $value = array('type' => 'text', 'value' => $value);
            if ($value['type'] == 'sql')
                $sql .= '`'.bqSQL($key)."` = {$value['value']},";
            else
                $sql .= ($null_values && ($value['value'] === '' || is_null($value['value']))) ? '`'.bqSQL($key)."` = NULL," : '`'.bqSQL($key)."` = '{$value['value']}',";
        }

        $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
        if ($where)
            $sql .= ' WHERE '.$where;
        if ($limit)
            $sql .= ' LIMIT '.(int)$limit;
        return (bool)$this->q($sql, $use_cache);
    }
```

Comment: To display the number of lines in the back office,  is accessing it via {$number_lines} the appropriate way in the .tpl?

Comment: if that is already assigned Smarty variable, yeah, that's good, but think you need to fix it to `{$number_lines|intval}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to undergo quite an extensive amount of dev "just to have a text field" ^^

You have to create the field in the `ps_product`table first (unsigned int).

Then add your fields to the `Product` class members (you need to override the product class first). 
Inside `/override/classes/Product.php`:

```
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public $number_lines;

    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        Product::$definition['fields']['number_lines'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt');
        parent::__construct($id_product, $id_lang, $id_shop);
    }
...
}
```

Then you have to override the `AdminProductsController` to add said field in the form, with the right type.
Finally you have to assign the field to the product inside the controller's `postProcess()` function.

Comment: The tutorial I linked to does not mention the overrides. Is there a 'best practice' way to do this (such as your method), or is it just kind of 'whatever works' ?

Comment: You can do it with hooks if you feel like building a module just for that. Might be cleaner. But you have to override the Product model nonetheless, otherwise you won't be able to register new values in your custom field.